# Removing string concentation from a file with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with over 4000 lines of text. Some of the lines are concentated with '+' at the end of the string. I need to remove all of the '+' concentations and join the strings together. I am reading line by line through the file and have tried line.endswith('+'), line.strip(). This might be an easy one, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can we see sample lines, and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to run a "Find and Replace". I don't know exactly what those lines look like, but if the "+" is really the last character and you want to remove them and add it to the next line, highlight everything starting with the + and ending just before the part you want to have added to that line, then (usually under the edit menu) open the "Find and Replace" option (sometimes just called "Replace") and replace it with a space or whatever seems most suitable for your case. Highlighting first should automatically add that selection to the correct field in the Find and Replace dialog.

You shouldn't really need programming for such a task unless you are looking to make a program that will do it many times automatically across multiple files or something.

Maybe an easy, lame answer, but it sounds like what you need.